# How to download Avi and VLC

Tags: vlc, video

I downloaded VLC to enable me to open an AVI file.
It didn't work.

So, I have two questions.

Is there another way to open AVI on my mac and how do I trash VLC from my computer?
Please keep it simple because so am I ;)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  One question per question and edit this to show a little research please. See [ask] for guidance on the research part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fair chance that what you downloaded was not, in fact a real .avi file but a hoax, a virus.

The chances of this are entirely dependant on ***where*** you got it - the BBC, 0%, PirateBay, 99%

However - **Don't Panic** - even if it was a hoax file, the chances it was a virus that could infect a Mac are infinitesimal.

VLC will play just about anything you throw at it - it really is the Swiss Army Knife of players -  so it's always a reasonable hint if it won't play it that you were sold a pup, or you just got a bad [corrupt] download.
VLC can show you any errors it encountered whilst trying to play a file -
Window menu > Errors & Warnings… or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>M</kbd> 
The output of that window might be fairly unintelligible, but you can use it to guess whether or not it even *thought* it was a real video, or whether it just was struggling with some esoteric format, or playback data error.

If in any doubt, or unless you are certain of the source - i.e. the BBC, then just trash it.

Comment: hmmm you may be on to something there....thank you for your help.

Comment: This is perhaps the reason others were recommending mkv or mp4 formats - all the really hoaxy stuff seems targeted at Windows traditional formats, avi & wmv etc. The hint is always [especially on a Mac, where you're theoretically immune to those Win exploits] that VLC really will play just about anything ever made with a moving picture in it. [& more]

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't download AVI's of you can help it. Look for MKV's or MP4's.

Depending on the format of the video in the AVI you may be able to play it with the Perian plugin for QuickTime.

VLC is a good player and will play MKV and MP4 files, but if you still want to remove it you can just drag it to the trash. If you want to remove all of its corresponding files then download a free app called AppCleaner and use that to remove it.

Comment: I don't know what a Perian plugin is....and I' can't find the flash drive now to open and try the MKV on the same flash drive. But it wasn't highlighted either to enable me to drag it anywhere..

Answer (score 0):

Let's first try and resolve the problem before quitting.

What steps did you take when trying to open an *AVI* file? Please state your OS X version and the version of VLC you are attempting to use.

If **right-click** > **open with** > (**other** >) **VLC** ...doesn't work, then I would try reinstalling VLC.

Comment: VLC said to drag the file into its box. None of the movies were highlighted to enable them to be dragged just the stick. So, I tried to drag it into the box. It didn't do anything....I have Yosemite version 10.10.5

Comment: Additionally I can't even find the drive on my finder or anything else for that matter, just VLC and my apps...